# on click on edit text, one custom list dialog box comes and list items should change according to the text change in edit Text, for android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview, customdialog

I am developing one android app for ice cream sandwich
I want to populate a dialog box containing list items(only one column) from database, on edit Text click, but list should get filter according to the text change in edit text. is that possible ?? 
Till now i am able to populate Dialog box containing all list items but i have no clue to filter this list according to edit text, this will work just like a search bar.

Comment: when dialog box appears on clicking edittext, then u wont b able to enter anything in edittext as all UI behind dialog box is un-accessible until n unless dialog box disappers

Comment: Thank you for response braj, but I am setting the position on dialog box, so edit text is visible.

Comment: yes, its possible. Edittext has got listener for text change... based on that changed text u could query database for matching elements, fetching them and displaying in dialog box listview...

Comment: Thank you braj, i will try , i think it is the answer.

Comment: u r welcome... wow wow wait wait, I wl post that as answer so that i can get some reputation ;)

Comment: sure braj :) , but i tried it in the same way then,, i am facing one issue, that is , whenever i change text in edit text.. again it popups the dialog box with updated list.. and hide soft keyboard for edit text, which is very annoying, can i change the text continuously and update dialog box list simultaneously??

Comment: could u post that code?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are looking for can be accomplished using AutoCompleteTextView in android.
It poulates a dialog everytime you enter letters in textfield.The Prdictions come from an ArrayList containing list of items.Also  as you said you can fetch list of items from database and put the items in arrayList from which predictions are displayed.

Here is one example according your need.

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Integrate Sqlitedatabse code with example given on above link to fulfill your needs.